# How to Return a JSON Object from an ASP.NET MVC Action Method

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

When I'm in a controller, I need to pass an entity object (`Product`) back to a view for use in JavaScript.

I pass a model object from the action method to the view. The model object contains some data the view needs for display, but also (the bit I'm struggling with) a JSON version of the product data.

In the view, I want to pick up the product object as JavaScript to play with.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewProduct( int  productKey )
{
    VendorPage page = PageManager.Instance().GetProductPage( );
    Product product = this.repoProducts.Get<Product>( App.GetVendorKey(), productKey );

    JavaScriptSerializer    sz = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = sz.Serialize( new { pr = product } );

    ProductPageModel  ppm = new ProductPageModel( page, product );
    // Embed the product as json in the model
    ppm.js = json;

    if ( product != null )
    {
        return View( "Product", ppm );
    }
    return null;
}
```

View - uses the model as ProductPageModel
@model  SiteEngine.SiteEngineUI.Models.ProductPageModel
html......

So, the question is: How do I gain access to the product in JavaScript, in order to do something like ...

```
alert( product.Name );
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the way you are returning, and trying to do it via JsonResult?

Comment: Not sure how to, I need to goto the required view from the controller as this is not an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var product = jQuery.parseJSON(@Model.js);
</script>
```

in case you don't use jQuery, take a look at http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: thanks, I do use jQuery, but didn't see parseJSON.  After some debug it does seem to work with the JavaScriptSerializer from the controller, except for text which has an ampersand in it - this was giving me a parse error until I found the problem.  The JavaScriptSerializer encodes ampersand (&) as \\u0026 whick kills the parser.

Comment: following on, there are serveral other js encoded characters in the text and they also cause the parseJSON to fail with invalid character.  Is there a technique that gets round this?

Comment: in fact, the serialized string in the controller looks like :

Comment: "{\"AvProductKey\":246,\"VendorKey\":1}"  // cut down version, but in the view, via    product = $.parseJSON( '@(Model.js)'); the string looks like '{&quot;AvProductKey&quot;:246,&quot;VendorKey&quot;:1}'.  The parser fails because of the &quot; i think.

Comment: try DataContractJsonSerializer instead on JavaScriptSerializer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

Comment: finally got to what's left - some of the attributes that JavaScriptSerialzer is encoding have quotes within them, so I get part of the serialised string for an attribute contains text like : ....\\\"Tourne, tourne petit moulin\\\".... which confises the jquery parseJSON call.